# SQL query with distinct records

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, inner-join, distinct

I want to get distinct records from the below query. I mean if we uncomment the commented lines.

Please help.

```
SELECT cs1.Nm AS CategoryType, cs2.Nm AS Category --, cs2.Nm AS sub_category
FROM Cat_Struct cs
INNER JOIN Cntrct_Cat cc
    ON cc.Cat_Struct_Id = cs.Cat_Struct_Id 
INNER JOIN Cat_Struct cs1
    ON cs1.Cat_Cd = cs.Cat_Cd AND cs1.Mkt_Cd IS NOT NULL
INNER JOIN Cat_Struct cs2
    ON cs2.Cat_Cd = cs.Cat_Cd AND cs2.Mkt_Cd IS NULL 
--join Cat_Struct cs3 
    --on cs3.Cat_Cd = cs.Cat_Cd AND cs3.Mkt_Cd is null 
--AND cs3.Sub_Cat_Cd is not null
WHERE 
    cs.LOB_Cd ='P' 
AND cc.Cntrct_Vers_Id = 781439637
AND cs2.Nm = 'adult books'
```

Comment: I tried sir, But that doesn't work its giving duplicate records.

Comment: Please remember that distinct only remove the rows wher there is whole record is repeated. if there is any change between 2 lines even a minor 1 distinct will keep both the rows.

Comment: Agreed sir... Can you help me in this query...

Comment: @AnkitBajpai if there are changes between the rows, then they aren't duplicated

Comment: @SrinivasaRao can you plz post some sample data and expected output.

Comment: Is hard for us reproduce this issue without a sample data or schema. You could create a simpler case similar to the one you one reproduce or create a small sample on sqlFiddle.com.

Comment: @SrinivasaRao We need **sample data** in order to test and see what is not working in your query. But, as other answers have said, you will get duplicate rows if any information in the selected columns are not totally identical, for two or more rows, which you don't want to show up.

Comment: see how create a simple schema http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5c2bd/3

Comment: I am not able to attach screenshot over here.

Comment: Don't need a screenshot. Copy and paste sample data into your question.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Keyword Distinct in select statement.

Yow will get the records which are not repeated.

Thanks